# Swift 5.5 + Apple Core Data — How can I store a simple formula as an item/attribute in a Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

#### I need to store simple math formulas IN Core Data for later use in/by my code.

Formula that **dictate quantities** and **conditions** under which a particular PDF Form will be included in an assembly of Forms.

- I am writing an iOS app for managing sets of PDF forms that are to be
  packaged together in various combinations.
- I have multiple classes of users (members of `User_A` and members of `User_B`).
- **New Forms need to be able to be added and "described" without *additional programming*.**

For example … a "set" of forms should have **1 copy** of `Form123`, **2 copies** of `Form456`, and **3 x (`User_A_Participants` + `User_B_Participants`) copies** of `Form789`.

I have created a "`Forms`" Entity in Core Data and defined many standard Attributes within the "`Forms`" Entity (e.g., `formTitle`, `formID`, `formVersion`, `pageSize`, etc.).

However, I do not know how to store "**3 x (`User_A_Participants` + `User_B_Participants`) copies**" as an Attribute that my code will later be able to decipher into an actual quantity to copy/print.

For many reasons, I need to use Apple's Core Data to handle the underlying storage. I am OK with restricting myself to Xcode 13, iOS 15 and Swift 5.5 (*I have no legacy anything that I need to worry about*). I'm also open to any Cocoa Pods that may help.

Please forgive if I use incorrect verbiage as I have never attempted this aspect of programming before.

THANK YOU in advance for any assistance/direction.

Comment: In my opinion, isn't your forms strings? And you could decipher those forms strings later on. If those forms are originally strings, you should be able to save them into Core Data.

Comment: Core Data is just an object persistence model.  While it does have some limitations on the attribute types it can store, you should ignore Core Data initially. Come up with a data model that reflects your requirements.  You have a `FormSet`.  A `FormSet` seems to contain one or more `Form`s.  A `Form` has an identifier/name, a quantity and an optional user class.  Your question implies that a `Form` can also actually be another `Formset` - Your 3x User A and 3 x User B.  Once you have a workable in-memory model then decide how to persist it in core data